when trying to access the contract from the browser, it says the listener argument must be of type function. received type object
TypeError: The "listener" argument must be of type Function. Received type object
    at checkListener (events.js:72:1)
    at _addListener (events.js:169:1)
    at module.exports.addListener (events.js:227:1)
    at http.request (index.js:38:1)
    at https.request (index.js:12:1)
    at FetchRequest.getUrl (geturl.js:42:1)
    at #send (fetch.js:462:1)
    at FetchRequest.send (fetch.js:512:1)
    at EtherscanProvider.fetch (provider-etherscan.js:217:1)
    at EtherscanProvider._perform (provider-etherscan.js:473:1)

events.js  is located in node_modules/ethers/lib/utils/
fetch.js is located in node_modules/ethers/lib/utils/
provider-etherscan.js is located in ethers/stream_httpfinder/

packages
C:\DEVEL\_BLOCKCHAIN\TESTS\html-test-6>npm list
my-html-test-6-project@1.0.0 C:\DEVEL\_BLOCKCHAIN\TESTS\html-test-6
+-- @metamask/sdk@0.20.5
+-- @types/node@20.12.12
+-- aes-js@3.1.2
+-- assert@2.1.0
+-- bootstrap@5.3.3
+-- browserify-zlib@0.2.0
+-- buffer@6.0.3
+-- bufferutil@4.0.8
+-- create-require@1.1.1
+-- crypto-browserify@3.12.0
+-- css-loader@7.1.2
+-- depcheck@1.4.7
+-- ethers@6.13.0
+-- html-webpack-plugin@5.6.0
+-- https-browserify@1.0.0
+-- install@0.13.0
+-- latest@0.2.0
+-- opensea-js@7.1.9
+-- os-browserify@0.3.0
+-- path-browserify@1.0.1
+-- stream-browserify@3.0.0
+-- stream-http@3.2.0
+-- terser-webpack-plugin@5.3.10
+-- ts-loader@9.5.1
+-- ts-node@10.9.2
+-- typescript@5.4.5
+-- url@0.11.3
+-- utf-8-validate@5.0.10
+-- vm-browserify@1.1.2
+-- web3-utils@4.3.0
+-- web3@4.9.0
+-- webpack-bundle-analyzer@4.10.2
+-- webpack-cli@5.1.4
`-- webpack@5.91.0


You need to provide context, share the code snippet so others can see and provide you with help.
